# Python - find recurring pairs/groups of values in dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, file-io, python-2.6

I have the following script, which loops over a text file of css rules, and stores each rule and its properties in a dictionary(improvements to code welcome, I've only just started using Python):

**findGroups.py**

```
import sys
source = sys.argv[1]
temp = open('pythonTestFile.txt', 'w+')
di = {}
with open(source, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # if line starts with . or #, contains _ or - between 
        # words and has a space and opening brace(ie is css rule name)
        if re.search('((([\.\-\'])?\w+\s?\{', line):
           key = line.replace("{", "")
           di[key] = []
           line = next(file)
           while "}" not in line:
               # remove trailing whitespace and \n 
               line = ' '.join(line.split())
               di[key].append(line)
               line = next(infile)
temp.close();
```

**source.txt**

```
* {
    min-height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftContainerDiv {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: white;
}

#cs_ht_panel{   
    font-family:10px;
    display:block;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    width:auto;
}
//...etc
```

Preferably, I would like the output to look something like this(suggestions for readability also welcome):

**pythonTestFile.txt**

```
Group 1, count(2) - font-family: Helvetica; + font-size: 10px;
Group 2: //...etc
```

What I want to do now is to figure out which css properties are reoccurring groups, so for example if font-size: 10px and font-family: Helvetica appear together in a rule, does this group occur in any of the other rules and how many times does it occur.

I'm not entirely sure where to go with this, I can't figure out how to even start some sort of comparison algorithm, or if a dictionary is the right data structure to store the text in.

EDIT: in response to a comment, I'm unable to use a third party library. This script will be used on a Red Hat VM, and only pre-approved software can be pushed onto these, I am unable to just download libraries or software packages

Comment: I don't mind a downvote, but at least explain why the question is downvoted so that I can fix it

Comment: Your endeavor is indeed writing a css parser. Wouldn't something like tinycss (https://pythonhosted.org/tinycss/) be a good starting point and modify or use it's API?

Comment: I'll add more detail to the question for this, but using a third party library isn't an option. This is for use on Red Hat VMs, and there are heaavy restrictions on what software we can use on these. Bascially we can't download any third party software, anything we used is pre approved by various people and pushed onto the VMs, So i only really have access to whatever programming languages or tools that are already installed on a Red Hat instance. I agree that maybe hand rolling/modifying/making use of an existing CSS Parser could make this simpler but unfortunately its not an option

Comment: Depending upon what their licensing is - you could cherry pick parts from there and go about it. So you essentially write by hand what you want, except that you don't start from the beginning and save yourself some time. Even then it might be much longer than a quick solution

Comment: The selectors that you want to look for will they only be 2 or 3 or in general any n?

Comment: @gabhijit As in, generally how many selectors will be present in the file? if so at last count for the particular file im working on it was around 60 different selectors, but there are a number of files to work through so any n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a different prime number to every css property, like:

```
{
    'diplay: block': 2
    'font-size: 10px': 3,
    'font-family: Helvetica': 5,
    'min-height: 1000px': 7,
    'overflow: hidden': 11,
    'width: auto': 13,
    'background: white': 17,
}
```

Then make a dict where the keys are the css selectors (what you call "rules") and the value is the product of all the properties it has:

```
{
    '#cs_ht_panel': 390, # 2 * 3 * 5 * 13
    '*': 77, # 7 * 11
    '.leftContainerDiv': 255, # 3 * 5 * 17
}
```

Now you can easily determine two things:

- What selectors ("rules") have a property `x` (indicated by its prime) or a set of properties `{x,y,z,..}` (indicated by the product of their primes) by looking if the selector number is divisible by that number.
  e.g. what selectors have both `'font-family: Helvetica'` (5) and `font-size: 10px` (3)? All and only those that are divisible by 15.
- All the properties two selectors have in common by calculating the GCD (greatest common divisor).
  e.g. GCD(390, 77) = 1 -> they have no properties in common
  GCD(390, 255) = 15 -> factorize -> 3 * 5

You can also find the most common groups by iterating over all the selectors values, find all the proper divisors that are not prime numbers and keep a dict that saves how many number that divisor has been found. Each divisor is a group, and you can find its elements by factorizing it.

- 390 -> 6 10 15 26 30 39 65 78 130 195
- 255 -> 15 51 85
- 77 ->

So you have two times 15, and all the others 1 time. Which means that there are 2 occurrences of the group 15, which is the group of property 3 and 5.

This last computational step is 2^n, where n is the number of properties in that css selector. It shouldn't be a problem as most selectors have less than 10 properties, but more than 20 properties and you start being in trouble. I would suggest compressing properties by removing prefixes (moz-, webkit-) and suffixes (-left, -right, -top, -bottom)

**You can (and probably should, for real CSS files with hundreds of lines) do all this just using sets and their operations (intersection etc.) instead of numbers, products and primes; but isn't this much cooler? ;)**

Comment: On re-reading your answer, so after the part where all css properties are given a prime, and the selector is assigned the product of these as a value, how would you search through this? Do you mean that the user would input the primes for groups they want to see are there, or should this be automated so that the script will run through the selectors and determine what groups are present?

Comment: That's the last part of my answer, starting with: "You can also find the most common groups by..."

Comment: ah yes i see, i think i understand your solution now.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on ideas explained above - instead of using prime number - I am using sets and ordered lists. May be this is what you want?

```
import re
import itertools

f = open('css_test.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
lines_str = ' '.join([l.strip() for l in lines])
#print lines_str

r = re.compile(r'.*?{(.*?)}') # Get All strings between {}
groups = r.findall(lines_str)
#print groups

# remove any stray spaces in the string and create groups of attributes like
# style: value
grps = []
for grp in groups:
    grps.append(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, grp.strip().split(';')))


# clean up those style: value attributes so that we get 'style:value'
# without any spaces and also collect all such attributes (we'd later create
# a set of these attributes)
grps2 = []
all_keys = []
for grp in grps:
    grp2 = []
    for g in grp:
        x = ':'.join([x.strip() for x in g.split(':')])
        grp2.append(x)
        all_keys.append(x)
    grps2.append(grp2)
set_keys = set(sorted(all_keys))

print set_keys
print '***********'
set_dict = {}
# For each combination of 2 of keys in the set find intersection of this
# set with the set of keys in the cleaned up groups above
# if intersection is the set of 2 keys: initialize a dictionary or add 1
for x in itertools.combinations(set_keys, 2):
    for g in grps2:
        set_x = set(x)
        set_g = set(g)
        #print "set_g : ", set_g
        if set_x  & set_g == set_x:
            print set_x
            if set_dict.has_key(x):
                set_dict[x] += 1
            else:
                set_dict[x] = 1

# print everything
print set_dict
```

Even if this solution isn't exactly matching what you want - may be you can follow the above line of thought to arrive at what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm having some trouble following your code(not your fault, i'm new to Python and using sets). Are you essentially making a set for each selector containing its properties and using intersection operations with every other set to find common pairs?

Comment: Short Answer - Yes. Long answer - Agreed code is not very readable. A lot of that code does nothing but cleaning up strings - so that we could 'uniquify' them. But let me explain the basic idea. Using regular expression to find 'groups' that of interest to us. Now we process 'each group',  For each group we obtain 'A-V' pairs. A collection of _all_ such A-Vs (as a string) will be a global collection of all A-Vs. Then we create all 'combinations' of 2 a-vs from this global collection and search for them in groups (intersection == 2A-vs) and finally collect them in a dict with occurrences. HTH